# Find the solution to the sum $\sum^{p-1}_{i=0} i^{k} \pmod p$, for prime $p$, positive integer $k$.

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

For some prime $p$ and some positive integer $k$:

$$\sum^{p-1}_{i=1} i^{k} \pmod p$$

Find the solution to the sum.

I've found that for $k=1$, the sum is equivalent to $\frac{p-1}{2} \pmod p$, but I'm not sure how to extrapolate it.

Comment: For $k=1$ and odd $p$ this is $\sum n = p(p-1)/2 \equiv 0 \pmod p$.

Answer (score 0):

If $k$ is a multiple of $p-1$ then $n^k \equiv 1 \pmod p$ for all $n \not \equiv 0 \pmod p$ and the sum is $-1 \pmod p$. Otherwise there is an $n\not \equiv 0 \pmod p$ such that $n^k\not \equiv 1 \pmod p$. Since $x \mapsto n x$ is a bijection mod $p$, multiplication by $n^k$ shows that the sum is $0 \pmod p$.